# comparing hash map string with list of strings?

Tags: java

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList();
a.add("one");
a.add("two");
a.add("one");
Map<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap();
map.put(1,list1);
map.put(1,list2);
```

How can I compare list a with list1 and list2?

Comment: you put two objects to the map for the same key. This does not make sense.

Comment: This seems more of a general Java question. Is this for part of a unit test?

Answer (score 2):

This is the example (I have fixed your map so that the construction does make sense)

```
@Test
public void testListCompare(){
    List<String> a = new ArrayList();
    a.add("one");
    a.add("two");
    a.add("one");
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
    list1.add("one");
    list1.add("two");
    list1.add("one");
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add("two");
    list2.add("one");
    list2.add("one");
    Map<Integer,List<String>> map = new HashMap();
    map.put(1,list1);
    map.put(2,list2);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry: map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(a.equals(entry.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Since you're using `ArrayList` it extends `AbstractList` that has `equals()` method overridden to properly compare the lists.

Otherwise if you implement your own `List`, you can use something like this:

```
public boolean ifListsAreEqual(List base, List candidate){
    if(base.size() != candidate.size()){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < base.size(); i++){
        if(!base.get(i).equals(candidate.get(i))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```